# CORS error when sending large JSON objects to Azure server

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have an issue when sending a big JSON object to a Node.js server which is deployed on an Azure server. When I send a big object which contains a lot of records from the client (React app) to the server, the console will display CORS warnings.

But when I send the same object locally, it will work OK. It seems like a policy of Azure. Does anyone know for sure if that may be the cause of my problem?

Comment: What is a "big object"? Can you post your example payload or at least its structure? Also does every request get rejected by CORS or just the one with the "big payload"? Can you also share some of your code and the exact error you are receiving.

Comment: Example like this "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UM6iRnBjNXPn3qAddzyJGYAYUy5R5qbs/view?usp=sharing" 
Sorry, because my English is not good. Others api is work fine. But when i sent request with this payload is the same in this file. In console browser displayed CORS. But in postman it display 413 Mod Sercurity Action.

Comment: Is that your React app runs on-premise or uses another domain?

Comment: I know bug cors. But all my APIs still work. This api sent a big payload still work when this payload is smaller. So i think the problem is the size of this payload. I requested my user to increase payload. But they said no because of their policy. :(